# does Paypal buy now button contains a parameter to check the success/failure of transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, web, parameters, paypal

Actually i want customers to pay for once in a life time to use my website by registering at my sign up page so that Next time when a paid customer enters the website , he/she will be asked to enter their login credentials to use it without paying again.

now if i use paypal buy now button, does it allow me to have a parameter (for my internal coding ) which checks whether the transaction is successful or not?   and redirects it to my mentioned page?

plus i am developing my website on google app engine (java)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it by passing an encrypted parameter to the return url

```
<input name="CANCELURL" value='errorurl' type="hidden"/>
<input name="return" value='returnurl' type="hidden"/>
```

These are the return and cancel url parameters. You can append the return value as a query string with the 'returnurl'

---

If you do not want to redirect to paypal and payment should be done in the page you provided, you can use [paypal express check out](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code). This method will not redirect the page to paypal.

Comment: u mean if the transaction is failed or unsuccessful then there will be no return parameter??